# Why the difference between Add12 and Kahan's summation algorithm?

Tags: floating-point

Consider the function `Add12` below, taken from [CRlibm's documentation](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/frs/download.php/16/crlibm-0.8beta3.pdf) with a couple of apparent typos fixed:

> Let `a` and `b` be floating-point numbers, then the following method computes two floating-point numbers `s` and `r`, such that `s` + `r` = `a` + `b` exactly, and `s` is the floating-point number which is closest to `a` + `b`.

```
void Add12Cond ( double *s , double *r, double a, double b ) {
  double z ;
  *s=a+b;
  if (ABS(a) > ABS(b)){
    z=s−a;
    *r=b−z; 
  } else {
    z=s−b;
    *r=a−z;
  }
}
```

This looks very similar to [Kahan's summation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) applied to `a` and `b`, with one glaring difference: Kahan's summation algorithm does not bother with first determining which of `a` or `b` has the largest `ABS`. It just takes summands as they come (and usually more than two of them).

I think that the Handbook of floating-point arithmetic invites the reader to think about this difference but does not give any explanation. Anyway, I have been thinking about it for a while and I still do not have any intuition for why Kahan's summation algorithm can do away with the `ABS(a) > ABS(b)` test (and I do not have the book at hand now that I am reminded of this question by a recent reference to Kahan's summation algorithm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put it simply, Kahan summation is going for a weaker error bound than `Add12`.  Kahan summation gets error bounded relative to the sum of the absolute values of the inputs.

Looking at `Add12`, it certainly computes `s` to be the closest thing to `a+b`.  The conditional is there to make sure that `z` gets computed exactly (casework!) and hence that `r` is "the rest of" `a+b`.  In particular, you get `r + s = a + b` and `|r| <= 0.5 ulp(s)`.

If we were to take the wrong branch in `Add12` but the magnitudes don't differ by more than a factor of 2 epsilon, `z` would be computed with an error at most `0.5 ulp(z)`, and so `*r` would be computed with an error at most `1 ulp(z)`.  So picking one branch of the two unconditionally means that we accumulate errors proportional to an ulp of the thing we assumed was smaller.  Kahan summation always assumes the new input is smaller, so it gets a total error roughly proportional to the sum of the absolute values of the inputs.

Kahan in his [original half-page paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=363707.363723) describing Kahan summation wrote the following, which conveys to me things Star Trek could not about the wild optimism of the 1960s:

> The convenient accessibility of double-precision in many FORTRAN and
>   some ALGOL compilers indicates that double-precision will soon be
>   universally acceptable as a substitute for ingenuity in the solution
>   of numerical problems.

Unfortunately, this half-page paper gives no bounds or proofs.  An error bound for Kahan summation is given as Exercise 19 in section 4.2.2 of TAOCP; the exercise states that the error arising from Kahan summation of x_1, ..., x_n is bounded by (2 epsilon + O(n epsilon^2)) (sum(i=1..n) |x_i|).

I was going to give a proof based on the setup in TAOCP here, but I have been repeatedly and embarrassingly butchering it for some time now.  Happily, I just found that [David Goldberg did this in the appendix to "What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic."](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: N.J. Higham, Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms 2nd ed, section 4.3, agrees with the above analysis. For proof of the improved error bound for Kahan summation he also points to TAOCP, Ex. 19, section 4.2.2, and for a more detailed proof to [Goldberg's seminal paper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). I have to admit I never noticed such a proof in Goldberg's paper, I should look again, more carefully this time.

Comment: The proof for Kahan summation in Goldberg's paper is in the section titled "Theorem 14 and Theorem 8": This section contains two of the more technical proofs that were omitted from the text. [...]

Comment: "... Kahan summation wrote the following, which conveys to me things Star Trek could not about the wild optimism of the 1960s:" - wasn't Kahan the bad guy?

Comment: @BrettHale: That movie was from the 1980s.  Different ballgame entirely.

Comment: @BrettHale: Whoa.  I wasn't aware of that.